Pandas divide by each value occurrence in one column
I have a dataframe which contains a column labeled Pool. I want to create a new column labeled "Volume" which is 310 divided by the occurrence of each value of Pool. For example there are three occurrences of Pool 1 so 310/3 = 103.3. There are 4 occurrences of Pool 2 so 310/4 = 77.5 and so forth. Any ideas on how to do this with Pandas?



Pool
Volume




1
103.3


1
103.3


1
103.3


2
77.5


2
77.5


2
77.5


2
77.5


3
62


3
62


3
62


3
62


3
62



I tried:
df["Volume"] = 310 / pool.get_group(1).value_counts()


Thanks for your help.

Use Series.map with Series.value_counts for counts per groups:
df["Volume"] = 310 / df['Pool'].map(df['Pool'].value_counts())

#alternative with division from right side - rdiv
#df["Volume"] = df['Pool'].map(df['Pool'].value_counts()).rdiv(310)

Or GroupBy.transform:
df["Volume"] = 310 / df.groupby('Pool')['Pool'].transform('size')


print (df)
    Pool      Volume
0      1  103.333333
1      1  103.333333
2      1  103.333333
3      2   77.500000
4      2   77.500000
5      2   77.500000
6      2   77.500000
7      3   62.000000
8      3   62.000000
9      3   62.000000
10     3   62.000000
11     3   62.000000

